# How to Use Rotation Sensor in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, sensors

I have a ball (bitmap) at the center of black surface View.

I want to move that ball to left of the screen, if we tilt the phone toward left.
Similarly for right side.

(Eg :- we control bike, in any bike racing android game).

Which sensor to use and how to gets its value.

The Code So Far......

```
public class ABC implements SensorEventListener {
public ABC(Context context){
sensormanager = (SensorManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensormanager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensormanager.registerListener(this, sensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}
.
some Code
.
@Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

    }
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show what you'be tried so far?

Comment: I have inserted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your code under onSensorChanged.

See example here:

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {

float[] values = arg0.values;
    // getting movement from x,y,z axis
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    }
```

Every time the sensor detects movement you get new values under the values[] array.
Now, you can use those values to do whatever you want.

It is good practice to register the listener under `onResume()` and unregister it under `onPause()`, like so:

```
 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // register the listener
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
        sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    // unregister listener
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }
```

Hope this has helped.

Comment: Question 1

Suppose I only want to use "X-axis"

So, what is the range for values[0]-->x-axis, i.e., min->0 max->something......like this ?


Question 2
can I write the statements for "Register/UnRegister" inside a thread that I have used in another class...MainThread.java.
i.e., inside thread's "join" or "pause"

Question 3
I am also using "Surface View".
So can I use "Register" statement when I create Surface View and "Un-Register" Statements inside "SurfaceDestroyed" method of SurfaceView.

Comment: 1. I advise you to read more about the sensor and values you get from it. Read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values)
2+3: It depends on how your project is constructed. Your SurfaceView is part of your Activity, so I still believe it is best to use the `onPause` and `onResume` to handle the registering of sensor listener. In that way you are sure to take care of the listener - activating it upon loading, and disabling when leaving Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the GYROSCOPE, not the ACCELEROMETER.

The Gyroscope tells you about the rotation around X, Y, Z axis.

Also have a look at the `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()` method.

Comment: Thanks !
Let me have a look at SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()